# Why is my favicon not found?

Tags: reactjs

In webpack I have the following code:

```
{
    test: /\.ico$/i,
    use : "file-loader?name=/[name].[ext]"
}
```

In my *index.html*, inside `<head>`, I have the following code:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

I placed my *favicon.ico* into the root folder (where also my *index.html* is placed). However, I get the following error:

> http:localhost:8080/favicon.ico (404) error

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Simply adding favicon in public dir do the job, no need to webpack for that

Comment: Which server you are using to run the application and do you have used url-loader in webpack config file?

Comment: @Gobinda ..... we are using express to run the application ...Yes ,i used url-loader in webpack.config.js file..

Comment: @MehdiDehghani....What to remove in webpack.config.js file.....I placed my favicon.ico in public directory only...It shows the same error..I think pblm in webpack.config file...can you help me what and where should replace code..Thanks in advance

Comment: Try serve-favicon with express. You need to just import it in your server file `const favicon = require('serve-favicon');`

Comment: And add this middleware to express. app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));